# Method not defined in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rgeo

I have a project with PostGIS integration through RGeo gem. Rails 4, ruby 2.1.

RGeo has standard method `contains?` which checks is point is located in polygon. Everything is fine in development (on MacOS X). But when I push my code to production server (Ubuntu 12.04) I have this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Method Geometry#contains? not defined.):
app/models/address.rb:28:in `block in define_courier_area'
app/models/address.rb:28:in `define_courier_area'
```

The code is very simple. I just need to return an array of all CourierArea instances, where are Address coords located.

**address.rb**

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  def define_courier_area # HAVE TO BE REFACTORED
    arr = []
    CourierArea.all.each { |ca| arr << ca if ca.poly.contains?(self.coords)}
    arr.first if arr.first
  end
end
```

I suppose, production environment can't obtain access to `contains?` method, which is provided by RGeo gem. How can I solve this problem? Maybe I should insert `require 'some_rgeo_file'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem has been solved.

RGeo uses some external libraries. For geometry calculations (distance, area, point-in-polygon) this library is GEOS. When I tried to invoke `contains?` RGeo was seeking for GEOS but it was not installed.

Moreover there is an RGeo method `RGeo::Geos.supported?` for checking GEOS availability. If it will return `false`, you probably has no GEOS installed or RGeo has problems with connecting with it. If it will return `true` – boya! you can use geometry calculation methods!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like RGeo might not be installed in your production environment. Run this:

```
gem install rgeo
```

That should fix it.